# Batch script output to text using a variable to name the output file

Tags: batch-file, command-prompt

I have never written a batch script before but would like to use one to run & write the output of a command line utility I use on a regular basis.  I would like it to write to a text file using a string returned by the utility as a file name (serial number in this case).  There are a few problems here.  The code ideally would:

1. use the utility to query the serial number of a device
2. parse the output of that query using the "=" delimiter, as it returns "serial = ##########" and I just want the number.
3. create a .txt file with the number as the filename, i.e ##########.txt
4. fill that file with information from subsequent calls of the utility using >> redirector

I have a bit of it in place, but I am struggling with having it parse the output into a variable and then use that variable to name the text file.  Currently it looks like:

1. utility > loo.txt
2. set /p sn=< loo.txt (here is where I would like it to delimit by = but can't figure out how)
3. utility >> %sn%.txt (where I would like it to append another call of the utility to the unique file for this iteration of the script)

Is this even possible? Helps!

Answer (score 1):

### Something like this should work

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=2 delims== " %%A in ('utility') do set "SN=%%~A"
utility>>"%SN%.txt"
```

#### See these great Batch resources

- [SS64](http://ss64.com/)
- [Rob van der Woude](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/batchfiles.php)
- [Computer Hope](http://www.computerhope.com/forum/)
- [DosTips](http://www.dostips.com/)
- [Technet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490909.aspx)

Comment: You'll have to add a space in the delimiter section if the serial data is as described above.